# Using Ansible Playbook Bundles with multiline secrets on Openshift

Tags: ansible, openshift

While using [Ansible Playbook Bundles](https://github.com/ansibleplaybookbundle/ansible-playbook-bundle) secrets are specified as in https://github.com/openshift/ansible-service-broker/blob/master/docs/secrets.md

However, multiline secrets do not seem to work as usual.

If secrets are added through [create_broker_secret.py](https://github.com/openshift/ansible-service-broker/blob/master/scripts/create_broker_secret.py), a multiline secret will change its newlines into spaces when it is parsed into the playbook bundle parameters.

If secrets are added manually as in:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
    name: test
    namespace: openshift-automation-service-broker
stringData:
    "test1": "test1"
    "test2": "test2"
    "test_multiline": |-
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      <FIRST LINE OF THE SSH KEY>
      <SECOND LINE OF THE SSH KEY>
```

the Ansible Playbook Bundle will see an error while loading the secrets YAML file, as if it was using newlines to separate secrets:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  could not find expected ':'
The error appears to have been in '/tmp/secrets': line 6, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
<FIRST LINE OF THE SSH KEY>
<SECOND LINE OF THE SSH KEY>
^ here
```

This issue is pretty frustrating when using SSH keys.

Do you have any idea how should multiline secrets be used with the Ansible Broker?

### **EDIT:**

I noticed that there seems to be a bug with the Ansible Playbook Bundle code.

On https://github.com/ansibleplaybookbundle/apb-base/blob/cc949ecfeee2e84bd626c73b4cbc54d496fc6738/files/usr/bin/entrypoint.sh#L48

```
for key in ${mounted_secrets} ; do
      for file in $(ls ${SECRETS_DIR}/${key}/..data); do
        echo "$file: $(cat ${SECRETS_DIR}/${key}/..data/${file})" >> /tmp/secrets
      done
done
```

As seen on this piece of code, mounted secrets are just copied with `cat` ignoring the fact that some of them might be multiline string blocks.

Any bug workaround is welcome.

Comment: You have a syntax error coming from the code you executed, but there is no single line of code in this question.